Polars Downcast the Datatype without Precision Loss
I've observed that when I use polars.Expr.shrink_dtype to optimize the datatype of columns, it often alters the float values slightly.
For instance, a float64 value of 2.7 becomes 2.7000001 when converted to float32.
However, when I use pd.to_numeric(df["col_name"], downcast="float") with pandas-numpy, I don't experience  this loss of precision.
Is there a method in polars to downcast the datatype without affecting the precision of float columns?

"with pandas-numpy, I don't experience this loss of precision". You are not seeing the loss of precision. Use pd.set_option("display.precision", 10) and print pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([2.7]), downcast="float"), and you'll see. You cannot downcast without losing some precision.

2.7 cannot be stored exactly in any kind of (binary) float. All that changes when you downcast is how many zeros there are between the 7 and the 1.
